Prove $\sup_{t >0} P(Z \geq t) e^{t^2/2} = \frac{1}{2} $, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable
Prove that
$$\sup_{t >0} P(Z \geq t) e^{t^2/2} = \frac{1}{2}, $$
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.
This is an exercise in a book on concentration inequalities and I have no idea how to proceed. Note that $P(Z \geq t) e^{t^2/2} \leq 1 $ is well-known.

Differentiate w.r.t $t$, you get $t \exp(t^2/2) \int_t^{\infty} \exp(-x^2/2)dx - 1 \leq 0 $, so it's decreasing and use the answer below be @geetha290krm

As $t \to 0$ we have  $P(Z\ge t)\to P(Z\ge 0)=\frac 1  2$ and $e^{t^{2}/2}\to 1$. So LHS $\ge \frac 1  2$.
